# Why would the military use tanks in a zombie apocalypse?

Tags: apocalypse, zombies

So usually the use of tanks is to shoot at other tanks or fortifications. So would a tank be useful against zombies? Would they just use it to crush the Zs?

Comment: A big metal box that zombies cant get into that has protection from nuclear, biological, and chemical attacks? Why *WOULDN'T* you use tanks?

You could just roll over hordes of zombies with your tank for lots of splats.

Comment: Sounds like somebody needs to fire this up using Ultimate Epic Battle Simulator.

Comment: So the protagonist's plucky side kick can say things like 'Tanks alot!' and 'Tanking of you, darling.' and 'I don't want to hear how we are holding our position, I don't want us holding anything but the Zombie by the nose, while we grease the treads of our tanks with their rotting guts.' and other such funny and inspiring witticisms.

Comment: Actually the military will use everything in their disposal, they are trained to do crowd control so why is it a surprise when they rolls out heavy vehicles? ;D

Comment: Wat weapons do the zombies have? And how intelligent are they?

Comment: If the tanks are completely sealed, how would the zombies know there were humans inside?

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond If the zombies are attracted by sound then it doesn't matter. They can be drawn towards the tanks by using guns and/or engines

Comment: Tanks are not mainly for shooting at other tanks or fortifications, but for crushing foot soldiers. Oh, and civilians. Rolling tanks into the streets to crush uprisings is a favorite tactic of communists. Prague Spring, Tian-An-Men square, ...

Comment: Crushing people isn't typical docterine. In combat, tanks have many other ways of ruining someone's day, often involving less gauche things.

Comment: @Kaz yes, tanks **are** mainly for shooting at other tanks and fortifications.  Crushing civilians is a side benefit.

Comment: @RonJohn OK, but at least the very first tanks were certainly not intended for shooting at other tanks, which the other side were assumed not to have. :)

Comment: @Kaz and the very first airplanes were not designed for what they do now.  IOW, the statement "**at least the very first tanks** were certainly not intended for shooting at other tanks" is totally and completely **irrelevant** to what **modern tanks** do.

Comment: @Kaz What would be your solutions for "uprsing" (so I'd rather call them "murderous terrorist scum") that burned unarmed recruits to a crisp and hanged their charred corpses from a bridge? Hint: check google image search for "tiananmen burned soldier". Make sure you're not eating.

Comment: RE: “Why...?”  Because 1) We already have tanks, and 2) Zombies do not have anti-tank weapons.  Armored cars would probably be more cost-effective but if you’ve already got a ton of tanks, you might as well use them.

Comment: Read the novel World War Z for a convincing description of an anti-zombie army.

Comment: Tanks have machine guns with lots of ammo, and often alo flame-throwers.

Comment: @DrMcCleod YMMV how convincing you consider WWZ. See for example a massive headscratchers section on Battle of Yonkers on tvtropes on WWZ.

Answer (score 66):

**It's the mounting platform for your flail.**

If you pull the tank battalion's [mine flail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mine_flail) ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqY39bCPeVM)) out of the back of the motor pool and put it onto the tank, you can shred your way through lots and lots (and lots!) of zombies.

[image: Mine Flail image courtesy of Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mine_flail#/media/File:M4a4_flail_cfb_borden_1.JPG)]
<sub>WW2 Sherman Tank Mine Flail. Uploaded to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mine_flail) by Balcer</sub>

You do need secure start points and endpoints for the trip. After all, you want that expensive tank (and its crew) back.

Oh, the endpoint needs a wash rack -- the gore may be quite deep by the end of a run.

You can use the approach for classic route clearance and convoy protection, or add big noisemakers on top to attract walkers for area clearance.

Comment: You don't need flails on all four sides. No zombie is going to penetrate tank armor. The only reason tanks are vulnerable to infantry is because they're thinking and have the ability to employ antitank weapons.

Comment: @stix agreed. Edited.

Comment: Somehow, I thought the chains didn't rotate very fast, and wouldn't cause much damage. After watching the video, I realize I was wrong.

Comment: Might want an extra air filtration system for the driver.  The mush mist will carry any virus or bacteria from the zombies.

Comment: @user2702772, there are CBRN-proof tanks. They're OK for a few days, until the human waste absorption pouches fill up...   However, they should be zombie-spray proof.

Comment: Agreed, this CBRN exist, I'm just pointing out that WW2 relics would need some work first?

Answer (score 29):

[**Flame tanks**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flame_tank)

[image: flame tank]

Flame tanks are a variation of battle tanks where either the main or secondary armament is replaced by a flamethrower. They haven't been developed much since WWII — the combat mission of tanks evolved in a different direction, emphasizing mobility and long-range firepower — but the adaptation is straightforward, and likely extremely effective against mindless ravening hordes.

All things considered, it might be more efficient to retrofit an Armored Personnel Carrier or Humvee with flame devices. The light armor of the those two is more than sufficient against zombies, and they have far better mobility and fuel efficiency. But parking a flame tank near the entry to a secure area should make that entry effectively impregnable.

Comment: Flame weapons haven't been developed much because of a certain Geneva Convention.

Comment: @Trioxidane: yeah, that too... 

Comment: @Trioxidane Fragmentary rounds are also against the Geneva convention but we still use them because they limit collateral damage.

Geneva says you can't use the weapons in war. It doesn't say you can't develop them.

Comment: Would Geneva Convention apply to zombies?

Comment: The Geneva Suggestion

Comment: @Alexander Dead bodies don't get human rights.  Even if the dead bodies are walking around.

Comment: @Graham. Technically dead bodies DO have some rights under the geneva convention. For example it is against the conventions to mutilate the dead bodies of the enemy. (For example putting heads on spikes in medieval fashion.)

Comment: My only concern here is that, unlike humans who would likely flee in terror, a burning zombie horde may well just keep surrounding your tank until they can't any more. And being buried under a still-moving pile of flaming, rotting flesh sounds distinctly unpleasant and quite possibly deadly.

Comment: @BThompson: Well... I suppose I have no right to make the *realistic* assumption that fricasseed zombies stop moving sooner rather than later. They may not be smart enough to run away, but if they're tough enough to plow throw a high-pressure jet of flaming fuel and keep on killing, then things aren't looking good.

Comment: TedWrigley That's a good point; I was thinking more about the kind of flame you get from an aerosol can (not that I'd ever do such a silly thing, of course...). Military flamethrowers are a different beast, and you're probably right that even without the pain zombies would be incapacitated pretty quickly by turning their muscles into ash. Whether that would happen before they could close the distance to the tank, I'm not sure. And eps, my concern isn't so much the zombies literally stopping the tank; it's a horde of flaming zombies dog-piling the tank and basically cooking it

Comment: A zombie apocalypse probably also means a fuel shortage, so squirting petroleum products out a nozzle might not be the most efficient thing to do with them, vs. heating your living space.  (Unless you use enough flame tanks to stop civilization from falling?)

Comment: Tanks in general have very low fuel efficiency, so IDK how big a difference it makes / how much more chemical energy this would use up.  I'm guessing standard flame thrower fuel wouldn't easily run a generator or gas-powered car.  But if you have to make flame-thrower fuel (sticky jelly-like petroleum product, I think) out of material that could instead have been used as or turned into diesel or other engine-powering fuel, it's probably not great if civilization has already fallen and oil production has mostly stopped.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Tanks _do_ have crap fuel efficiency, but modern tanks with gas-turbine engines (like the Abrams) make up for it by being able to burn practically anything combustible that can be pumped (as long as it doesn't produce refractory oxide particles or droplets when burned, as these are bad for turbine blades), from kerosene to petrol to Kentucky moonshine to olive oil to Chanel perfume to creamy peanut butter.

Answer (score 25):

*Before there are more pedantic comments arguing about the exact definition of "Tank" - for the purpose of this answer I use [the Merriam Webster definition of "Tank"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tank): "an enclosed heavily armed and armored combat vehicle that moves on tracks"*

Tanks have armor which is impervious to zombies trying to claw at them. The are often air-tight (in case the zombie virus is transmitted by air). Their tracks enable them to free themselves even if enveloped by a huge zombie crowd which might be too much for a vehicle with wheels. So if you want to do a scouting mission in an area overrun by zombies, then a tracked tank would be the safest way to do that.

The main gun of a battle tank would be overkill against zombies, but battle tanks are usually equipped with at least one machine gun, which should be pretty efficient at neutralizing zombies. Still, if you have the luxury of being able to choose which tank to use, you might want to opt for a lighter armored personnel carrier so you don't consume as much precious fuel.

Comment: Why use a tracked tank over a tracked APC? equally impervious to anything the human body is capable of, and generally equipped with weaponry focused on the anti-personal role like 20mm canon. And have significantly more payload capacity.

Comment: @user1937198 I would consider an APC a type of tank.

Comment: A tank is a specific type of vehicle with a specific role on the battlefield. I think the term you are looking for is armored fighting vehicle, which covers a range of systems from self propelled artillery, armored personnel carriers, armored cars, and assault guns, all the way up to main battle tanks.

Comment: @user1937198 I am not sure a "tank" is so clearly defined, but I suspect you mean an MBT, a main battle tank?

Comment: @Mayou36: If you exclude WWI vehicles, a vehicle designed primarily for offensive manovoure warfare against opposition vehicles. If you want to include the WWI tanks: a vehicle designed to be the lead element in offensive manovoure.

Comment: Oh boy, I see this expand into a 20+ comment discussion arguing about semantics.

Comment: @user1937198, please provide a source, otherwise Phillip gets right ;)

Comment: @Mayou36 Is wikipedia good enough: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tank 'A tank is an armoured fighting vehicle intended as a primary offensive weapon in front-line ground combat.' Thats not a vehicle where transport is the primary purpose.

Comment: @user1937198 yeah, I'd *definitely* prefer an M2 Bradley IFV.  The 25mm chain gun and .30 cal machine gun are much better suited for wiping out zombies.  Too bad it's not NBC capable.

Comment: Minor nits. 1) Tanks are not "air tight", rather they maintain a positive pressure so the outside air cannot get in. 2) The general term covering tanks and APCs is "Armored Fighting Vehicle" (AFV). 3) The M2/M3 has been NBC capable for decades.

Comment: @user1937198, yes, we agree. And it is wider than just other opposition vehicles (as mentioned in the comment), it can also be against person. So e.g. an IFV is a tank? But anyway, it doesn't matter; my point was it is not as narrow and Wikipedia agrees: it's a vehicle with primary offensive capabilities. Not per se against other vehicles.

Answer (score 21):

## Tanks can be easily configured to attack zombies

Tanks are flexible and can serve a variety of missions. For example, the M1 Abrams, the main tank used by the US Army, can fire the M1028 Canister Cartridge:

> The 120mm M1028 Canister Cartridge was developed for close-in defense
> of tanks against massed assaulting infantry attack and to break up
> infantry concentrations, between a range of 200-500 meters, by
> discharging large numbers of tungsten balls from the main cannon. ([Source](https://www.gd-ots.com/munitions/large-caliber-ammunition/120mm-m1028/))

That sounds like an ideal anti-zombie round. Additionally, the M1 can have up to four machine guns. Imagine a massive hoard of zombies lurching toward a tank that's firing canister rounds and four machine guns.

Comment: Canister would be devastating, but tanks carry only about 40 rounds for the main gun, and unless they're specially loaded, only a few would be anti-personnel. Plenty of ammo for the machine guns.

Comment: @Schwern: If the tanks are being sent out to fight zombies, wouldn't one _expect_ them to be specially loaded for zombie?

Comment: @Vikki-formerlySean Depends on the scenario. There's a limited supply of anti-personnel rounds for the M1, and if logistics break down no guarantee it will reach that tank. Either way, you'll have 40 rounds of main gun fun, don't expect more. Then it's machine guns and treads. When the turbine drinks all its fuel it's just the machine guns. 900 rounds of .50 will run dry fast, but 10,000 rounds of 7.62mm for the coax and roof is pretty common and will last a long time with good fire discipline. When the ammo runs out it's an immobile armored box.

Comment: Even once empty the main gun is still useful. Rotate the turret to knock zombies off the tank.

Comment: Adding to this, those canisters work because your target feels pain and if critically wounded will stop moving. Depending on your type of zombie these may be nearly useless, if all you're fighting is zombies, wouldn't be better to scrap that room for machine gun ammo that you can target more accurately? Even regular rounds would be better due to the larger impact and trauma damage if shoot at the ground, would they not?.

Comment: Indeed - grapeshot ought to drop the zombies fast.

Answer (score 15):

They would (in most zombie apocalypses) not be used for offensive purposes. At best they would be used in a defensive (stationary) way.

This is because during a "typical" zombie apocalypse supply lines would grind to a halt meaning that it would be difficult to keep a steady fuel supply. And tanks use a lot of fuel. A tank like the M1 Abrams gets about 0.6 miles per gallon. A Humvee (a faster vehicle that is also armed and armored and easily able to charge through a crowd of zombies) can get 12 miles per gallon meaning you can have 20 Humvees operational for each tank you leave behind.

So best use for tanks would be simply to become part of a barricade and use the machine gun (perhaps the main gun) on top. And if the barricade get's overrun they could always hide inside the tank and wait for rescue or if there is some fuel left ball back to reestablish a new line.

Comment: A line of tanks could form a fairly effective barricade, especially considering that they could be employed to disable any hordes that congregate on the other side of the barricade. I can imagine a city block being reclaimed by a line of tanks rolling through.

Comment: Zombies might be able to penetrate a HMMV though. An armored tank that can be equipped with a cow catcher to just mow zombies away has its obvious benefits. 
Tanks and HMMVs don't use the same fuel either. An Abrams uses jet fuel, a HMMV uses regular gasoline.

Comment: @stix yea and which would be easier to get a steady supply of, regular gasoline or jet fuel? And you will need to be able to store 20 times as much fuel for a tank to cross the same distance as a HMMV 
Also in what way would a zombie be able to penetrate the armor of a HMMV? Also you should consider the added benefit of of speed, maintenance and movability.

Comment: @stix tanks would be great for the beginning, but in the long run they would be highly inferior to any form of armored personal carriers.

Comment: @A.bakker That's precisely when you would need tanks the most. The beginning is when the zombie horde will be at its largest, densest, and most dangerous. Expend your biggest and most perishable weapons in the beginning. Save the smaller stuff for long term survival.

Comment: @A.bakker, the gas turbine on the Abrams (Honeywell AGT1500) can use jet fuel, gasoline, diesel, or marine diesel.

Comment: @KeithMorrison what percentage of tanks in the world are outfitted with an engine like that? and if said engine would break down how easily would it be replaced ?

Comment: @KeithMorrisonyou are missing my point on how easily replaced. i am not talking about the actual process but on how easily it would be to acquire more of those engines. And concerning the others that can use basic fuels...you get the issue that they are not fuel efficient compared to acceptable alternatives like armored vehicles. During a basic zombie apocalypse you need to do long term planning...if you throw out all your fuel in the first weeks by fueling all your tanks you will be doomed later on.

Comment: @KeithMorrison also in a basic zombie apocalypse the military (Semi) collapses and require new civilian recruits, a car mechanic would be more able to maintain a carlike vehicle like a Humvee then a tank. same goes for basic operating of a tank compared to a armored personal carrier of any kind.

Comment: As long as it's got the range to get you to the Winchester until it all blows over.

Comment: @A.bakker There is a precedent for aero engine technology (albeit not jet) in tanks : the Rolls Royce Meteor was mostly Merlin parts (without the supercharger) - it could use rejected parts like pistons, and field repairs were possible using scavenged aero engines.

Comment: @KeithMorrison On paper it can - but it depends what you consider "running". In a previous job I worked on car engine controllers, and I asked a colleague (a proper qualified engine expert) about this. He said that at best, on the wrong fuel it would turn the engine over and kind of run well enough to move, but that was about it. And you could expect to need an engine rebuild afterwards. The idea that you can put just any fuel into it and run it normally is basically fiction, apparently.

Answer (score 10):

#### They wouldn't, because of fuel consumption and maintenance

You don't have to agree with everything [Max Brooks wrote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_Z), but if you're talking zombies then you need a compelling reason to go down a different path.

Your biggest problem when you're facing zombies is not the zombies directly in front of you, it's the zombies over the entire rest of the country.  Someone needs to make your army's supplies, and more people need to transport those supplies to your army.  As Napoleon found out in Russia, if you can't supply your army then your army can't fight.

Brook's US military, dramatically on the back foot and desperately evolving effective tactics, came up with the concept of "kills per resource expended".  (I think that's the right phrase.)  Any weapons system was assessed based on how many extra zombies it could take out for the cost in resources to produce it.  Aircraft and vehicles were assessed as only being resource-effective for transport of people and equipment.

Sure, a tank can plough through zombies, so long as it's got fuel and it's well-maintained.  But the [M1 Abrams only gets 0.6mpg, and an armoured division needs 600,000 gallons of fuel a day](https://www.forbes.com/2008/06/05/mileage-military-vehicles-tech-logistics08-cz_ph_0605fuel.html).  And you might only get [1000km](https://boards.straightdope.com/t/how-far-can-i-go-before-changing-the-tracks-on-my-tank/197100) before you need to change the tracks, which you would certainly do inside a week of constant action.  When your factories and fuel refineries are mostly out of action because of zombie infestations nationwide, you need to radically conserve your resources.  Is it better to use that fuel and steel for a tank for a day, or is it better to use that fuel to transport a thousand extra troops and food to sustain the attack for a month, and use that steel to equip them all with anti-claw mesh armour and battle-axes?

Answer (score 9):

Zombies go for the flesh of the humans.

Tanks are really hard to open cans, and are proved capable of running over bodies.

They made a good protection for the humans they carry inside tasked with killing the zombies.

Comment: Armored Personnel Carriers are better... they are also hard to open cans, but can fit more people inside and are faster.  It also meets the threshold weight of "crush a zombie to dead again" that a tank would.

Comment: @hszmv APCs don't have as strong of an AoE attack as a tank. A 150 mm round is going to take out a lot of clumped up zombies. You can put a cattle catcher or an anti-mine flail on the front of a tank too. You can't do that with an APC.

Comment: How would the zombies know there were humans inside?

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond big rumbly noise = brainz

Comment: @stix "A 150 mm round" I think only the Russians have a 150mm cannon.  Everyone else uses 120-125mm. "is going to take out a lot of clumped up zombies." Do zombies clump up like that?

Comment: @RonJohn Zombies tend to roam around in a horde, so yes, they do clump up like that.

Comment: @stix our definitions of "clump" might be different.  Only canister shot can take out personnel who aren't standing in a long line standing down the axis of the barrel of the gun.

Answer (score 5):

Some of the [first tanks deployed in anger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_heavy_tanks_of_World_War_I#Mark_I) were fundamentally designed to overrun entrenched infantry positions. While modern tanks are less directly designed for this purpose, they're likely more effective at it.

Also one of the safest places you could possibly be during a zombie invasion is inside an armoured vehicle of some kind, even if all you're doing is sitting it out. While you're likely to use lighter armoured vehicles for getting about the place, any armour being good enough to keep zombies out, there's certainly a use for tanks in the larger equation.

Answer (score 4):

While the general idea of a tank is as a mobile platform for fighting other tanks - there's also several advantages to a modern tank or AFV.

One can't break a window, or swarm a tank as easily, and a swarmed tank can button up and wait for assistance.

I'd prefer a smaller [AFV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armoured_fighting_vehicle) or [IFV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infantry_fighting_vehicle) to a [MBT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armoured_fighting_vehicle) - but generally you have a vehicle that's designed for rough/unimproved terrain, against an enemy who cannot effectively use anti tank weaponry or penetrate even the weakest of tank armours.

If we're talking main battle tanks, they're an odd choice. You might be able to outfit them with specific improvements for more effective zombie killing.  Military vehicles do often have modifications to specific threats, like anti RPG slat armour. You might have electrified outsides for zombie zapping, spikes to make climbing up a tank dangerous, or even the use of claymores as a form of reactive armour

Effective use of an MBT might be as a 'mobile' pillbox or command unit. Move em somewhere you expect a zombie presence, lager them, with defences like concertina wire, and use their night vision equipment, height and superior firepower to clear the nearby area. You might also use lighter screening elements to herd the zombies into the most efficient fields of fire. Essentially tanks form a great core for a temporary base, as well as local firesupport.

That said, even the [75mm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMX-13) pop guns on the AMX  13 are hardly the *right* tool for the job. While anything you hit has had all its days ruined, its overkill, and you really are not going to carry more than 20-30 rounds. Tank guns are best used for effect, possibly with specific ammunition types.

Your 7.62mm or .50 cal co-axial guns might be a better option (even more so than conventional infantry 5.56mm rounds), since you don't really want to *wound* zombies as much as blow off meaty chunks.

The classic [M113](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M113_armored_personnel_carrier), while having armour marginally more useful than cardboard, with a remote weapons platform might be a perfect pillbox. Drive it over, use the .50 caliber to chew up those zombies, and scoot away to rearm, refuel and rest.

Personally, perhaps in a fit of national pride, I'd prefer something like the [bionix 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bionix_AFV) You have a lovely turret with a 30mm cannon, cause nothing says "goodnight" like a 30mm round (the same calibre as the famous GAU-8 Avenger of thunderbolt fame uses). You have *two* (three? I can't remember) additional 7.62 guns for lovely fields of fire

Even the adorable little [weasel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiesel_AWC) is going to get you much more efficient throw weight than a hummer.

If you want something with a little more flexibility, and want to not rip up the streets, a MRAP type vehicle would give you a lot of the same firepower advantages, though aren't really designed with the same sort of throw weight.

I don't really think there's any real contemporary literature on the use of indirect fire from mortars or artillery but depending on the density of the zombies, and available fields of fire these might also compliment an armoured lager/firebase well. You can carry, transport, or use armoured units that are capable of fire support for this.  I'll leave the implications of responsible use of artillery and anti zombie landmines to be considered by the reader

Comment: M113 "having armour marginally more useful than armour"?  Is the 2nd use of "armour" used as a synonym for main battle tanks?  Or is there an editing mistake in there somewhere.  Anyway, not clear what you're saying, since I'm not familiar with the good / bad points of the M113.  (Would also be good to expand or hyperlink AFV = Armoured Fighting Vehicle (I think) and other acronyms on first use.)

Comment: The M113 has aluminum armour. Against a "real" antitank weapon, that's roughly as useful as cardboard.

Answer (score 3):

**Because there are no better options**

Of all terrestrial vehicles, tanks are the most zombie-resistant. Their weight and off-road capabilities make them almost entirely impervious to zombie attacks. Zombies will have to make a pile of bodies big enough to have any hope of stopping a tank. So, whenever the military needs to get from point A to point B, and air transport is not an option, tanks become the primary choice.

And this is not to mention very broad offensive capabilities of tanks listed in other answers.

Comment: To tanks really offer better transport options than NBC capable tracked APCs? The only significant difference is the lighter weaponry, and armour, neither of which is going to be significant. And APCs have much more carrying capacity.

Comment: @user1937198 of course, if our evaluation is based on some other metrics like fuel economy or payload capability, tanks are going to lose. But they do offer superior protection. A horde of zombies may be able to swarm an APC and make it overturn, while tank would just keep plowing through it.

Comment: @user1937198 Bradleys don't have NBC capability (though some Soviet designs do).

Comment: Bradleys weigh about 30 tons (no flipping them over!), are tracked, and their 25mm auto-cannon would be damned effective at mowing down zombies.

Answer (score 3):

**Tanks are just lawn mowers for zombies**

No number of zombies can take out a tank. A tank weights around 60 tons and not enough zombies can get close enough to flip it or even damage it, not even World War Z zombies.

[image]

They're loud and attract the zombies to you making clearing an area faster and safer.

The only real addition you need is a drone above you or a spotter so you can see if you get covered in zombies.

If the worse happens, you turn the tank off and wait for them to leave. They can't get you inside.

It's a safe way to exterminate zombies.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the questioner is getting at a good point, which is that tanks are usually employed to achieve strategic objectives in a manner different from infantrymen or other tools in your arsenal. The main gun on a tank doesn't seem likely to be very effective at destroying hordes of zombies approaching from all directions, but the tank's ability to maneuver over hordes and its impenetrability seem like huge advantages. The tank's main assault weapon would be, in this case, a machine gun or some unconventional weapon like a flame thrower or the chain apparatus already mentioned. Their other utility would be as a scouting instrument, though perhaps LAVs might be more effective here.

The tank would likely be deployed in tandem with infantrymen performing house clearing operations. This is because the tanks can provide high firepower and protection for the infantrymen while the infantryman can clear a city or other region zone by zone. This is similar to how the Marines operated in the second battle of Fallujah. I should point out that armored personnel carriers would be an invaluable asset in this mode of combat, allowing the infantrymen a means to deploy and maneuver quickly. This type of maneuver would be more difficult if only tanks (combined with infantrymen) were used.

The more interesting point this question is getting at is "what does victory mean in such a war?" War is typically defined as the use of violence or the credible threat of violence to achieve political ends. Tanks are effective tools in this front because their armor and awesome firepower allow for the destruction or capture of strategic objectives. This, along with their intimidation factor, allows for the accomplishment of strategic goals. These types of goals would ostensibly be irrelevant against the type of enemy you're considering.

If you're considering such a military scenario, you should read "We Were One" by Patrick O'Donnell. This is an account of the battle in Fallujah, where combined arms were used to clear zones block by block as I imagine you are considering. If you're including military strategy in general the manual everyone should read is "Warfighting", a USMC publication which is the standard reference for militaries the world over for how to conduct war.

Answer (score 1):

The military would use tanks because they would be very effective against zombies, contrary to what fiction says. They're impervious to anything zombies can do to them. They can outrun zombies (especially if you disable the engine governor), with their turret facing the zombies. Anti-personnel rounds can carve through hordes like pie slices, hitting brains wouldn't even be necessary. And they have multiple machine guns.

Comment: Hi Jack, welcome to Worldbuilding! Did you read through the existing answers? Yours doesn't add anything new to them, which is something we discourage, as it only adds noise to the existing information. Please take the [Tour] to familiarize yourself with our platform.

Comment: For my zombies they do not need to be hit in the brain to die, anything that can kill a human will kill a zombie except some poison gasses or poisons.

Answer (score 0):

simply put you put yourself into a good bit of mobile armor that can defend against physical and aerosol attacks that also allows Crowd-Control capabilities without being exposed. Coaxial machineguns, front mounted machine guns, or even just canister shot. Heck even white phosphorous will do lots of damage to unarmored and unprotected crowds of the already half-rotten corpses. if you run out of munitions, you have a good engine to take you away or to go on a ramming spree (although the latter is ill advised due to possibility of damage to the tracks; might injure your possibility of getting away. But the tank is only as good as its team; you will need repair teams to help keep the combat team most efficient.